# Is the sentence correct: I am gonna lifeguard

Tags: grammar

> I am gonna lifeguard. (from a movie)

"gonna" is equal to "going to" so it should be written like: 'I am going to **be** lifeguard', what I think. 'be' was omitted, it's strange. It's a common omission?

Answer (score 2):

It is not proper English. It's an idiom to use a noun as though it were a verb; the complete sentence might be "I am gonna go be a lifeguard" or "... be the lifeguard".

Using "be lifeguard", without an article, would also be incorrect English.

Comment: "*It's an idiom to use a noun as though it were a verb...*" Are you not aware that *to lifeguard* is listed as a verb in dictionaries?

Comment: I was not. Wonder if that's recent? Sometimes treating nouns as verbs gets so common that some dictionaries will just give in and describe them that way.